# retrieving the text of an element in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

When I was using jsoup to parse some html files like "google.com" I encountered
with a problem in retreiving the text of an element.

For example in this `div` element using the `text` function, the words
"Programs" and "Business" are attached to each other which I think
it's not right:

```
<div id="fll" style="margin:19px auto;text-align:center">
   <a href="/intl/en/ads/">Advertising&nbsp;Programs</a>
   <a href="/services/">Business Solutions</a>
   <a href="https://plus.google.com/" rel="publisher">+Google</a>
   <a href="/intl/en/about.html">About Google</a>
</div>
```

You can test my claim with this code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
Document document = Jsoup.parse(url, 10000);
Element element = document.select("div[id=fll]").first();
System.out.println(element.text());
```

Output will be:

```
Advertising ProgramsBusiness Solutions+GoogleAbout Google
```

I want to know that can anything to be done about it?

By the way I traced the code and found out that the problem will be
corrected by adding this line:

```
textNode.text(textNode.text() + " ");
```

between the lines 755 and 756 of the `Element` class of the `nodes` package of the `jsoup` source code.

Also  this problem exists in `Elements` class of the `select` package and probably in other `text` functions!

Answer (score 3):

The `text()` method in jsoup returns only the text in an element.  In your example, your element is a `div`.  When calling the `text()` method on it, all of the tags are essentially removed and the text remains.  Since Programs doesn't have any space after it, it looks as though it slides right up on Business, which in this case is correct behavior.

If you want the text separately, you can do something like this (untested code):

```
for (Element a : div.select("a")) {
     System.out.println(a.text());
}
```

Comment: I was just following your example HTML.

Comment: You only considered the Element class, but how about the Elements class? This problem raised in that class too. Surly such results (concatenating words that logically are independent) in this case, are quite wrong. Although this is possible to manually avoid such wrong results. And finally about Element class, do you think in general case (that we have no knowledge about a super element, or in other words about a parent element) it would be good that the jsoup supply another API for these cases? Thanks.